# How To Confirm IMPDP is success or not in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-administration, datapump, impdp

i imported full database from 10g to 11g using DATAPUMP,
But below is the final message which i got.

**Job "SYS"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" completed with 5345 error(s) at 20:03:01**

how can i confirm it's success or not ??

how to know the source database objects are imported successfully.

any option to verify datapump method???

Comment: Read this Oracle doc to test import or export success https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39904_01/hcm92pbr0/eng/hcm/hpyi/task_ExportAndImportTesting.html

Answer (score 1):

> ... completed with 5345 **error(s)**

I don't know about you, but five **thousand** errors doesn't look like a *success* to me.

Have a look at the **log file**, it'll provide a view to details of what happened during the importing session.